socket.send stops working after first send in pysimplegui loop
I am trying to build a simple gui including a qr-code reader to send data to a remote server in python on Ubuntu for a school-project. I have set up a simple server to receive messages from the scanner via tcp/ip:
import socket
from Crypto.Cipher import AES


def main():

    # Server mit gegebener Adresse starten

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind(("192.168.1.40", 9999))
    server.listen()

    while True:
        client, address = server.accept()
        msg = client.recv(1024).decode('ASCII')
        print(msg)        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

If I run a simple test client all messages are received:
import socket

client = socket.socket()
try:
    client.connect(("192.168.1.40",9999))
    for i in range(1,10):
        client.send("\nHallo Server, ich bin dein Client und will was\n".encode('ASCII'))
except:
    print("Server nicht verfügbar\n\n")

and I get 9 messages printed row by row on the server.
The actual gui is
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from pyzbar import pyzbar
import cv2
import os
import socket
import math
from time import time, sleep
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

H1 = 0

def read_qr():
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    qr = False 

    while(not qr):
        ret, frame = vid.read()
        qr = pyzbar.decode(frame)        

    duration = .1
    freq = 3000
    os.system('play -nq -t alsa synth {} sine {}'.format(duration,freq))

    qr = qr[0].data.decode().split(':::')
    vid.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    return qr    


def si_msg(body):
    global H1
    H1 += 1
    H2 = socket.gethostname().split('-')[2]
    H3 = 0
    H5, H4 = math.modf(time())
    H6 = 2
    H7 = len(body.encode('ASCII'))
    si_msg = " ".join([str(H1), H2, str(H3), str(int(H4)), str(int(H5*10**8)), str(H6), str(H7), body])

    return si_msg


def main():

    sg.theme('PythonPlus')   
    status = 'Verbindung getrennt'
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(2.5)
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    layout = [  [sg.Text('Server-Adresse:'),sg.Input(key = 'k_server', default_text='192.168.1.40:9999')],
                [sg.Button('Server bestätigen')],
                [sg.Text('Status:'), sg.Text(status, key = 'k_status')],
                [sg.Exit()]]

    window = sg.Window('Virtueller Login', layout)



    while True:     

        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            break
        elif event == 'Server bestätigen':
            status = 'Verbindung zum Server wird hergestellt'
            window['k_status'].update(status)

            server = values['k_server'].split(':')

            try:
                client.connect((server[0],int(server[1])))
                status = 'Verbindung hergestellt: ausgeloggt'
                window['k_status'].update(status)
            except:
                status = 'Verbindungsversuch fehlgeschlagen'
                window['k_status'].update(status)
                sg.popup('FEHLER: Server nicht gefunden. Bitte prüfen Sie die Adresse oder wenden Sie sich an den Administrator')
                continue


        window.start_thread(lambda: read_qr(), 'Code gefunden')

        if event == 'Code gefunden':
            qr = values[event][0]
            msg = si_msg(qr)
            print(msg)
            client.send(msg.encode('ASCII'))
            sleep(2)



    client.close()
    window.close()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Running this main enables me to scan a qr-code/ barcode, which is successfully wrapped in the header (I have to make this ugly thing) and printed for each scan, iterating the scan-counter H1 with each scan. I am not getting any errors on client or server, but the server only receives the first scan.
To make sure it has nothing to do with the multithreading handled by pysimplegui I have omitted the lines
window.start_thread(lambda: read_qr(), 'Code gefunden')

if event == 'Code gefunden':
   qr = values[event][0]
   msg = si_msg(qr)
   print(msg)
   client.send(msg.encode('ASCII'))
   sleep(2)

and replaced them with a direct scan command (freezing the gui):
qr = read_qr()[0]
msg = si_msg(qr)
print(msg)
client.send(msg.encode('ASCII'))

This let's me enable the connection, scan the code, send the message and then the loop seems to stop working and I can not scan anymore. I can press the connect-button of the gui a second time, thus "reconnecting" to the server (which was never disconnected?) scan again, but it wont send a message to the server and won't establish the connection a third time.
Alternatively, simply adding a second message manually does also not get send, this does not work either:
qr = read_qr()[0]
msg = si_msg(qr)
print(msg)
client.send(msg.encode('ASCII'))
sleep(0.5)
msg = si_msg(qr)
print(msg)
client.send(msg.encode('ASCII'))

The counter iterates and is printed, but no second message is send, the connection seems lost, i can reconnect, scan again (without sending any of those messages) and that's it, again no third chance.
As I don't get any errors I am somewhat lost on this. I don't think it has anything to do with pysimplegui, as the consecutive manual messages don't get send either, but I have no Idea and would be happy for any help...

You are sending in a loop but you aren't receiving in a loop: you are receiving one message per accepted connection. You need an inner receive loop, which probably needs to be in a separate thread started by the accept loop.

But I AM receiving multiple messages without an inner receive-loop, as my first example does exactly that, and player0's answer below also makes it possible to receive multiple messages with the same loop of accept and get, albeit still not solving my original problem

try:
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import socket
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
from pyzbar import pyzbar
import cv2
from time import time
import math

H1 = 0

def read_qr(q):
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    qr = False
    while not qr:
        ret, frame = vid.read()
        qr = pyzbar.decode(frame)
    qr_data = qr[0].data.decode().split(':::')
    vid.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    q.put(qr_data)

def si_msg(body, counter):
    global H1
    H1 += 1
    H2 = socket.gethostname().split('-')[2]
    H3 = 0
    H5, H4 = math.modf(time())
    H6 = 2
    H7 = len(body.encode('ASCII'))
    si_msg = " ".join([str(counter), H2, str(H3), str(int(H4)), str(int(H5 * 10**8)), str(H6), str(H7), body])
    return si_msg

def connect_to_server(server_address, port):
    try:
        client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client.connect((server_address, port))
        return client
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error connecting to server: {e}")
        return None

def main():
    sg.theme('PythonPlus')
    status = 'Verbindung getrennt'
    server_address = ""
    port = 0

    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Server-Adresse:'), sg.Input(key='k_server', default_text='192.168.1.40')],
        [sg.Text('Port:'), sg.Input(key='k_port', default_text='9999')],
        [sg.Button('Server bestätigen')],
        [sg.Text('Status:'), sg.Text(status, key='k_status')],
        [sg.Button('Scan', disabled=True)],
        [sg.Exit()]
    ]

    window = sg.Window('Virtueller Login', layout)
    client = None

    qr_data_queue = Queue()

    def handle_scan():
        Thread(target=read_qr, args=(qr_data_queue,)).start()

    while True:
        event, values = window.read(timeout=100)
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            break
        elif event == 'Server bestätigen':
            server_address, port = values['k_server'], int(values['k_port'])
            client = connect_to_server(server_address, port)
            if client:
                status = 'Verbindung hergestellt: ausgeloggt'
                window['Scan'].update(disabled=False)
            else:
                status = 'Verbindungsversuch fehlgeschlagen'
                sg.popup('FEHLER: Server nicht gefunden. Bitte prüfen Sie die Adresse oder wenden Sie sich an den Administrator')
            window['k_status'].update(status)
        elif event == 'Scan' and client:
            handle_scan()
        elif not qr_data_queue.empty():
            qr_data = qr_data_queue.get()
            if qr_data:
                msg = si_msg(qr_data[0], H1)
                print(msg)
                client.send(msg.encode('ASCII'))

    if client:
        client.close()
    window.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


If I replace elif client and event == 'Scan': with if client: (and import math) It will give me exactly one scan and send the message. But I have two problems: the gui freezes, meaning I can't abort the scan action which makes the threading pointless
And I cannot scan consecutively, after each scan I have to verify the server again. But at least I can now scan every time, the message is send every time, and it does not stop working after two messages
What I don't get is why the elif client doesn't work, as the client is not reset with the next loop iteration, and there's no other event

Ok, now it allows to scan multiple times without breaking or freezing, but it still sends only the first message

edit: what "works": verify the server, then scan, message is send -> verify again, scan again etc. sends every single message - seems to me the connection is somehow terminated after the first send? But netstat says the server is still connected and I can print the client directly before the send-command - I am even more confused now, as that seems to be a server-related issue now, but that does not fit the initial possibility to send multiple messages in a row in a simple client?

@Puki indeed it should work, but I wouldnt bet my life on it that it is not some server or timeout issue

Ok, brute force check: I just wrapped the server's client.recv()in a while True: loop and now I am receiving every message.
Although I have no Idea why it did not work before, as for my understanding a once accepted connection should not have to be reestablished  - respectively if it has to do something with the .accept command the simple example should not have worked as far as I can tell...
So I will play with the server and build something to check if a connection is new, if so to create a new thread looping over something like a .isalive() function ...
